# How to correctly setup a CSS hover overlay image side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to create a CSS hover images side by side, except when you scroll over one it shows text on top of the other. I partially got it to work except I am dealing with a z-index problem. If I roll over the left image, it shows the hover for the right image. I tried playing with the z-index but I couldn't get it to work. I created a code pen here

https://codepen.io/chrisgrim/pen/MZxVax?editors=1100

HTML

```
<div class="overall-contain">
<div class="hover-box">
<div class="hover-box-content">
<div class="hover-box-content-overlay left1"></div>
<p><img class="hover-box-content-image" src="https://trulycreativedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/rollover-test1-under.jpg" /></p>

<div class="hover-box-content-details fadeIn-bottom left1">
<h3 class="hover-box-content-details">Text Over</h3>
<h4 class="hover-box-content-details">Here<h4>
<h4 class="hover-box-content-details small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="hover-box">
<div class="hover-box-content">
<div class="hover-box-content-overlay right1"></div>
<p><img class="hover-box-content-image" src="https://trulycreativedesign.com//wp-content/uploads/2019/01/rollover-test-under.jpg" /></p>

<div class="hover-box-content-details fadeIn-bottom right1">
<h3 class="hover-box-content-details">Second</h3>
<h4 class="hover-box-content-details">Over<h4>
<h4 class="hover-box-content-details small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
/* rollover image */
.overall-contain{
  display:flex;
}

.hover-box-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-flex;
}

.hover-box-content .hover-box-content-overlay {
  background: rgba(42,72,74,1);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hover-box-content .hover-box-content-overlay.left1 {
    width:200%;
  background: url('https://trulycreativedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/rollover-test1-over.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hover-box-content .hover-box-content-overlay.right1 {
    left:-100%;
  width:200%;
  background: url('https://trulycreativedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/rollover-test-over.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hover-box-content:hover .hover-box-content-overlay{
  opacity: 1;
}

.hover-box-content-details {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index:10;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align:left;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hover-box-content-details.left1{
  margin-left:100%
}

.hover-box-content-details.right1{
  margin-left:-100%
}

.hover-box-content:hover .hover-box-content-details{
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you clarify what it should look like. Are you saying to you two images to appear at the same time? Both over the top of the current ones?

Comment: I have two images side by side. When I hover over one, I want words and a background color to cover the other one. So if I hover over the left image, I see a new left image and a green background with text on top of the right image. If I hover over the right image, I see a new right image with a green background and text on top of the left image.
If you hover on top of the right image it works in the correct method.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want this to look like. You really need to use JavaScript "mounseon" and "mouseoff" to add CSS classes to get this affect. If you provide an image to help explain I can help a bit more.

Comment: Hi Christopher, here is a link to an image of what I am trying to do. https://trulycreativedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/rolloverhelp.jpg
Thanks so much! I was trying to do it just with css, but I see maybe I might have to use JS

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to show/hide the div. Use the mouseover/mouseout events to run javascript that will add remove the CSS that you need similar to:

```
<div onmouseover="show();" onmouseout="hide();>
LEFT DIV
</div>

<div id="RIGHTDIV">
RIGHT DIV
</div>

function show(){
   //This will add the CSS class that makes the div visible
   document.getElementById("RIGHTDIV").classList.add('CSSCLASSNAME');
}

function hide(){
   //This will remove the CSS class that made the div visible
   document.getElementById("RIGHTDIV").classList.add('CSSCLASSNAME');
}
```

If you need more information let me know and ill give you a more comprehensive answer. Thinking about this you can make this a lot more complicated if you are dealing with touch devices, different dimensions and variable content sizes.

Comment: This totally makes sense. I am going to have to change how I did the overlay, but I think they will help me accomplish it! I did notice that a " was missing onmouseout="hide();>
Thanks so much!!